# Remove __MACOSX/ files from zip archive using javascript and fflate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, zip

I'm testing [fflate](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate) to replace JSZip that sometimes will fail to open archives created using macOS or windows built-in compression utility. The library works fine and I'm able to create and read zip files content. I've done a test with an archive created using macOS and I've noticed that inside the achive the compression utility will create some `__MACOSX/_.filename.ext` files for each entry of the archive. I want to remove these files from the file list when the user open the zip using my app but I don't know how to proceed. Is there any solution I can use with vue and javascript to achive this?

Here is the code I'm using in my vue methods to read zip files

```
    async handleFiles(e) {
      const file = await this.readFile(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
      const unzip = unzipSync(file);
      Object.keys(unzip).forEach( (key) => {
        this.files.push({name: key, data: unzip[key]});
      });
    },
    readFile(file) {
      return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          resolve(new Uint8Array(reader.result));
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: This is a well-known "feature" of Finder's built-in ZIP utility (https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder). Checking `!key.startsWith('__MACOSX/')` to filter is the best solution. Side note, you may want to use the asynchronous `fflate.unzip` for parallelization: https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate/blob/master/docs/README.md#unzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Array.filter?

```js
Object.keys(unzip)
.filter(key => {
   return !key.match(/^__MACOSX\//);
})
.forEach( (key) => {
   this.files.push({name: key, data: unzip[key]});
});
```

Comment: No, at the moment I'm using the `str.startsWith()` function but also filter can be fine. Thanks for the help